# Recommendation for a free and small DNS server for Windows

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I'm looking for a free (GPL or BSD) and lightweight DNS server that runs on Windows, which I can use as a server for my coLinux installation, which, when configured via slirp, always gets the Windows server as it's only DHCP-assigned DNS server (I can't hardcode it in colinux as something like 4.2.2.3, since I often travel to places where outgoing DNS is blocked, and I want whatever rules are configured in Windows to be used for the linux process as well).

Bonus points [virtual points, that is...] for something that's portable.

Comment: what windows OS are you running?

Answer (score 4):

[Unbound](http://unbound.net/index.html). It is by far the easiest to setup on Windows. Just download and run the installer and you're done. Uses less than 8Mb of memory on my server, much less than Microsoft DNS.

Answer (score 3):

[This should be a guide for getting BIND running under Windows](http://alex.charrett.com/techstuff/bind9-win2k.html)

As an alternative, you might consider setting up a lightweight linux distro as a virtual machine under VirtualBox or similar.

Comment: He said "lightweight", running linux in a VM just for DNS is not lightweight, lol.

Comment: @ColinM............ROFL

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on Wikipedia there are quite a few to go at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_server_software

I Vote for bind as it has web management.

Answer (score 1):

DeadWood from MaraDNS - 66 KB exe file, and fully configurable.
https://maradns.samiam.org/deadwood/